# Name Capture, need a list of numbers

Tags: regex

I need to produced a named capture of numbers in a list

Example Source Data

```
This is a comment on line 1
Here is another Comment Line 2
Log ID 1234,5555,2342
```

using: `(?<id>(\d+)*)` I will pick up the results of

```
1
2
1234
5555
2342
```

But this picks up `1` and `2` in error.   I need it to pick up the items after Log ID Only.

I am looking for a regular expression that will return

```
1234
5555
2342
```

In a named group called `id`

Comment: are there multiple log ID's like that on a line in the real data??

Comment: Is the string 'Log ID' always there? Are there always three IDs? Are they always comma-delimited?

Comment: Is it always in the exact same format `Log ID 1234,5555,2342`?

Comment: Yes it is always the same format Log ID 1,2,3  But it also can be Log ID 1  (With only one item in the list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your language supports variable length lookbehinds, you should be able to use the following:

```
(?<=Log ID.*)(?<id>\d+)
```

I also made some modifications to your original regex, because I don't really see the point of the additional capture group inside of the named capture group, or the nested repetition (`(\d+)*` is equivalent to `(\d*)`, but I think you actually want `\d+` so that it requires you to match at least one digit).

If you can't use variable length lookbehinds (most languages), then you will probably need to do this in two steps.  First match any lines with 'Log ID' then look for numbers in those lines.

Comment: You can't use variable length in a lookbehind.

Comment: @Jack - In .NET regex (and possibly others) you can.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you.   Each of the other solutions presented had small problems.

Answer (score 0):

Would a negative look behind assertion do the trick?

```
(?<![Ll]ine )(?<id>\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also without look(ahead|behind):

```
"Log\s+ID\s+((?<id>\d+),?)+"
```

This will give you each of the numbers in a separate group named `id`

- `Log\s+ID\s+`: match the ID that you are after, but don't capture
- `(?<id>\d+),?`: capture the number and allow an optional comma after it (but don't capture)
- `+`: repeat at least once

However, this introduces a problem because you will have several groups with the same name - it depends on the language how this will be handled.

Alternatively you can use this regex to capture the whole string after Log ID into one group:

```
"Log\s*ID\s+(?<id>(?:\d+,?)+)"
```